# How do I change the window titles (as used by wmctrl)

Tags: command-line, workspaces, window

I am using [wmctrl](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/) to move applications after I have launched them such that I do not have to do this manually for, for example, several text editors and web browsers and pdf viewers and terminals. I am issuing the following wmctrl command to move applications around

```
wmctrl -r <title> -e <x>,<y>,0,-1,-1
```

where < x > and < y > are the horizontal and vertical target coordinates, and < title > is the name of the application as returned by `wmctrl -l`. If I launch two copies of google chrome via the below commands,

```
google-chrome &
google-chrome &
```

then issue the command

```
wmctrl -l
```

the window names returned are

```
0x03c06fd9  0 main New Tab - Google Chrome
0x03c0703d  0 main New Tab - Google Chrome
```

now if I try to move one of those to an arbitrary coordinate, lets say 100,100, with the following command

```
wmctrl -r "Google Chrome" -e 100,100,0,-1,-1
```

It will, if you haven't already guessed it, move THIS google chrome window I am currently typing in, as I opened it prior to the other two.

Is there some way to assign these window titles when launching from the command line, or to reset them later. I need to change the names to something like

```
Google Chrome 1
Google Chrome 2
Google Chrome 3
```

---

Note there are two ways around this that I am aware of, however, I do not like either of them, for they could lead to problems if the OS launches a program in the background.

1. Instead of using the title, use the numerical window ID via the `-i` command.
2. Use the string `:ACTIVE:` to use the active window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `xttitle` program from the `xttitle` package. Note the TWO "t"s in x**tt**itle. Well, actually, there are 3 "t"s... but I've only had trouble mistyping the first two.

Here's an example from my `~/.bashrc`, in which I override the `cd` builtin, and use `xttitle` to put the current directory in my window title:

```
# from the "xttitle(1)" man page - put info in window title
update_title()
{
    [[ $TERM = xterm ]] || [[ $TERM = xterm-color ]]  && xttitle "[$$] ${USER}@${HOSTNAME}:$PWD"
}

cd()
{
    [[ -z "$*" ]] && builtin cd $HOME
    [[ -n "$*" ]] && builtin cd "$*"
    update_title
}
```

Comment: if you google `xttitle` it says 'did you mean xtitle' =P

Comment: So how do you use `xttitle`?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka I updated my answer wirth an example, but you should have read `man xttitle`